# Add installer says Service name contains invalid characters, is empty, or is too long

Tags: c#, windows-services

I've created a service, when I right click and press create installer, I get the above error message.

The service name is not missing and is valid.

The problem is probably in that I have a base class on my service, with a couple of properties and an empty constructor.

Basically looks like this:

`EmailService : MyService`

`MyService : ServiceBase`

The EmailService is a partial class, and the constructor calls `InitializeComponent();` in the designer, which sets the servicename.

I am guessing I've done something silly regarding my base class that's breaking it or confusing it. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know the max length of the service path but I am betting the install ends up calling the sc create command in the following manner : 
sc create ServiceName binpath= "C:\<PROJECT_FOLDER>\bin\Debug\ServiceName.exe"
net start ServiceName
PAUSE...perhaps you can manually install it through a .cmd file and see if it yields a better indication of the problem.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Is the name set programmatically only? This is not recognized by the system. Right-click your service in design view, click `Properties` and make sure `ServiceName` is set.

Comment: Thanks. What a silly error. At least its an easy solution.

Comment: Thanks @Dunken you saved my time.

Comment: Isn't this a bug? How you came to knew about this fix?

Comment: Meanwile, this error was occured for me when I created my service class by hand...