# Windows Service Installer - Service name contains invalid characters, is empty, or is too long

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, windows-services, windows-installer

I've been following [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a(v=vs.110).aspx) about writing a Windows Service and accompanying installer. When I try to add the installer project and I right-click on the Design View and select 'Add Installer' I receive the following message:

`Service name contains invalid characters, is empty, or is too long`

My service name is set to "UploadManagerService". This doesn't contain any invalid characters that I'm aware of and is below the specified 80 character limit.

I've read several articles on here about this problem. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22641171/add-installer-says-service-name-contains-invalid-characters-is-empty-or-is-too) suggests that this is because the service name isn't set in Visual Studio though this is set in my case. I've also tried [setting the service name in the app.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8516701/how-to-get-windows-service-name-from-app-config) to see if that make any difference. Is there something else I could be missing or a way around this?

Comment: That's the VDPROJ way to do a service not the windows installer way. Would you consider trying an answer that uses MSIs ServiceInstall table rather then an unneeded custom action?

Comment: @ChristopherPainter - Thanks, I'd not considered that. I'd just followed the tutorial without thinking about going down the MSI route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would consider watching this:

[Create and Package a Windows Service using IsWiX](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bxbcPnjfzIc)

You can really simplify the problem by eliminating the use of InstallUtil and using native MSI functionality.  In fact, you'll notice that video only took 2 minutes and half that time is used to create the actual service.

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to understand what the problem was with the name but I was able to get round the problem by writing the installer manually with a few lines of code.

Assuming that you're follow the [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a(v=vs.110).aspx) and get the same problem after selecting 'Add Installer':

- Select 'ProjectInstaller.cs' on the Solution Explorer and hit F7 / right-click and select 'View Code'.
- If the constructor isn't present for the class, add one or edit the existing 
  constructor.

Add the following code:

```
var process = new ServiceProcessInstaller {Account = ServiceAccount.LocalSystem};
var serviceAdmin = new ServiceInstaller
{
    StartType = ServiceStartMode.Manual,
    ServiceName = "MyServiceName",
    DisplayName = "My Service Display Name"
};

Installers.Add(process);
Installers.Add(serviceAdmin);

InitializeComponent();
```

After this I carried on with the instructions on the MSDN article and was able to install the service with InstallUtil.exe.

I'm still none the wiser as to why this won't work but hopefully this will help someone else get round the problem.

Comment: Considering this answer solved my problem and is technically correct would the person who downvoted it care to explain what warranted the diwnvote?

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this exact error and everything was supposed to be fine. You read the error message fast, you blame it and then start checking the project's name, names of the classes and... wait a moment:

[image]

The [MSDN tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/walkthrough-creating-a-windows-service-application-in-the-component-designer?redirectedfrom=MSDN) names this step:

> In the Design tab, select Properties from the shortcut menu. From the Properties window, change the ServiceName value to MyNewService. [image: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/media/windows-service-properties.png]

I simply didn't follow the tutorial when I built the service, so remember folks: read the error messages and check every single point it's complaining about!